# Converting hex into a string using 'sprintf'

Tags: c

I am trying to convert an array into hex and then put it into a string variable. In the following loop the printf works fine, but I can not use sprintf properly. How can I stuff the hex values into the array as ASCII?

```
static unsigned char  digest[16];
static unsigned char hex_tmp[16];

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  printf("%02x",digest[i]);  <--- WORKS
  sprintf(&hex_tmp[i], "%02x", digest[i]);  <--- DOES NOT WORK!
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a very bad error description. Does it crash? Does it give compile errors? Does it give no errors but unexpected results? What unexpected results? What would you have expected instead?

Comment: A partial answer to your question is here: What is (16 * 2) + 1?  Your loop runs from 0 to ??.  How many iterations is that?

Answer (score 14):

```
static unsigned char  digest[16];
static char hex_tmp[33];

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)  {
  printf("%02x",digest[i]);  <--- WORKS
  sprintf(&hex_tmp[i*2],"%02x", digest[i]);  <--- WORKS NOW
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps you need:

```
&hex_tmp[i * 2]
```

And also a bigger array.

Comment: because you're printing out 2 characters for every 1 element in the array.  your target hex_tmp needs to be 16 * 2 + 1 digits long usually (* 2 because you have twice as many digits as elements of your digest, + 1 because normally you null-terminate strings in C).  Don't forget a hex_tmp[32] = 0 at the end.

Answer (score -2):

A char stored as numeric is not the same as a string:

```
unsigned char i = 255;
unsigned char* str = "FF";
unsigned char arr1[] = { 'F', 'F', '\0' };
unsigned char arr2[] = { 70, 70, 0 };
```