# C++ converting vector to 2 hex and then store it in a string

Tags: c++, vector, hex, printf

I have been using mostly C so I am pretty new into c++. I want to convert a int vector (std::vector) into hexadecimal representation and then store that into a string. I found something I would use in C in the following thread: [Converting hex into a string using 'sprintf'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770616/converting-hex-into-a-string-using-sprintf)

The code proposed by user411313 is the following:

```
static unsigned char  digest[16];
static unsigned char hex_tmp[16];

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  printf("%02x",digest[i]);  
  sprintf(&hex_tmp[i], "%02x", digest[i]);  
}
```

One of my concerns is that this could go out of index at some point since sprintf may try to add a 0 after the content. Also, I was wondering if there is any way to do it with native C++, perhaps any built function could be used instead of C functions. Is this preferable in c++ over c functions? Thank you very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 2):

> if there is any way to do it with native C++, perhaps any built function could be used instead of C functions. Is this preferable in c++ over c functions?

Sure there is a way, and yes it's preferable:

```
static std::array<unsigned char,16> digest;
static std::string hex_tmp;

for (auto x : digest) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (unsigned)x;
    hex_tmp += oss.str();
}
```

> One of my concerns is that this could go out of index at some point since sprintf may try to add a 0 after the content.

That's a valid concern. The classes used in my code snippet above will overcome all these issues, and you don't need to care about.

Comment: Your `hex_tmp += oss.str()` (in the loop) will append the *entire* content of the buffer for each digit. I don't think that's your intention

Comment: @BiagioFesta Oh, yes. Thanks for noticing. I fixed that.

Comment: @user0042 - better fix it other way around - move oss constructor and += outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

```
std::string hex_representation(const std::vector<int>& v) {
  std::stringstream stream;
  for (const auto num : v) {
    stream << "0x" << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << num
           << ' ';
  }
  return stream.str();
}
```

Obviously you can remove the `"0x"` prefix if you don't need it

[Here a live demo](https://ideone.com/URsKEy).

Comment: won't give OP the 2 character width that printf does.

Comment: You're doing too much assumptions about the desired output format. From the original code there won't be a `0x` prefix or separating `' '` planks.

Comment: @user0042 Yeah, you're right, but I've intentionally do that because the live demo is clearer about the hex conversion.